# Unload User Data in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

How can I totally unload User Data Session when I sign out, restart or shutdown my PC in Windows 10? Because I always have continuously error recorded in event viewer every time I sign out from my account or restart/shutdown my PC.
It is multiple Event ID 7031:

1. The Contact Data_Session2 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
2. The Sync Host_Session2 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
3. The User Data Access_Session2 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
4. The User Data Storage_Session2 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service.

Sometimes it became xxxx_Session1, sometimes became xxxx_Session 3 or 4 or 5.
Mainly it's about User Profile Session.

In detail Tab Contact Data_Session(x) service:

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
  [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
  [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager

  - EventID 7031

  [ Qualifiers]  49152

  Version 0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Opcode 0

  Keywords 0x8080000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2015-09-06T20:48:56.836213500Z

  EventRecordID 11938

  Correlation

  - Execution

  [ ProcessID]  636 
  [ ThreadID]  8464

  Channel System

  Computer XXXXX-PC

  Security
- EventData

  param1 Contact Data_Session2 
  param2 1 
  param3 10000 
  param4 1 
  param5 Restart the service 
  500069006D0049006E006400650078004D00610069006E00740065006E0061006E00630065005300760063005F00530065007300730069006F006E0032000000

---

Binary data:

In Words

0000: 00690050 0049006D 0064006E 00780065 
0010: 0061004D 006E0069 00650074 0061006E 
0020: 0063006E 00530065 00630076 0053005F 
0030: 00730065 00690073 006E006F 00000032

In Bytes

0000: 50 00 69 00 6D 00 49 00   P.i.m.I.
0008: 6E 00 64 00 65 00 78 00   n.d.e.x.
0010: 4D 00 61 00 69 00 6E 00   M.a.i.n.
0018: 74 00 65 00 6E 00 61 00   t.e.n.a.
0020: 6E 00 63 00 65 00 53 00   n.c.e.S.
0028: 76 00 63 00 5F 00 53 00   v.c._.S.
0030: 65 00 73 00 73 00 69 00   e.s.s.i.
0038: 6F 00 6E 00 32 00 00 00   o.n.2...

Detail Tab Sync Host_Session(x) service:

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
  [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
  [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager

  - EventID 7031

  [ Qualifiers]  49152

  Version 0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Opcode 0

  Keywords 0x8080000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2015-09-06T20:48:56.836213500Z

  EventRecordID 11937

  Correlation

  - Execution

  [ ProcessID]  636 
  [ ThreadID]  8464

  Channel System

  Computer XXXXX-PC

  Security
- EventData

  param1 Sync Host_Session2 
  param2 1 
  param3 10000 
  param4 1 
  param5 Restart the service 
  4F006E006500530079006E0063005300760063005F00530065007300730069006F006E0032000000

---

Binary data:

In Words

0000: 006E004F 00530065 006E0079 00530063 
0010: 00630076 0053005F 00730065 00690073 
0020: 006E006F 00000032

In Bytes

0000: 4F 00 6E 00 65 00 53 00   O.n.e.S.
0008: 79 00 6E 00 63 00 53 00   y.n.c.S.
0010: 76 00 63 00 5F 00 53 00   v.c._.S.
0018: 65 00 73 00 73 00 69 00   e.s.s.i.
0020: 6F 00 6E 00 32 00 00 00   o.n.2...

Detail Tab User Data Access_Session(x) service:

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
  [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
  [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager

  - EventID 7031

  [ Qualifiers]  49152

  Version 0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Opcode 0

  Keywords 0x8080000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2015-09-06T20:48:56.836213500Z

  EventRecordID 11940

  Correlation

  - Execution

  [ ProcessID]  636 
  [ ThreadID]  8464

  Channel System

  Computer XXXXX-PC

  Security
- EventData

  param1 User Data Access_Session2 
  param2 1 
  param3 10000 
  param4 1 
  param5 Restart the service 
  550073006500720044006100740061005300760063005F00530065007300730069006F006E0032000000

---

Binary data:

In Words

0000: 00730055 00720065 00610044 00610074 
0010: 00760053 005F0063 00650053 00730073 
0020: 006F0069 0032006E 0000

In Bytes

0000: 55 00 73 00 65 00 72 00   U.s.e.r.
0008: 44 00 61 00 74 00 61 00   D.a.t.a.
0010: 53 00 76 00 63 00 5F 00   S.v.c._.
0018: 53 00 65 00 73 00 73 00   S.e.s.s.
0020: 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 32 00   i.o.n.2.
0028: 00 00                     ..

Detail Tab  User Data Storage_Session(x) service:

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
  [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
  [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager

  - EventID 7031

  [ Qualifiers]  49152

  Version 0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Opcode 0

  Keywords 0x8080000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2015-09-06T20:48:56.836213500Z

  EventRecordID 11939

  Correlation

  - Execution

  [ ProcessID]  636 
  [ ThreadID]  8464

  Channel System

  Computer XXXXX-PC

  Security
- EventData

  param1 User Data Storage_Session2 
  param2 1 
  param3 10000 
  param4 1 
  param5 Restart the service 
  55006E006900730074006F00720065005300760063005F00530065007300730069006F006E0032000000

---

Binary data:

In Words

0000: 006E0055 00730069 006F0074 00650072 
0010: 00760053 005F0063 00650053 00730073 
0020: 006F0069 0032006E 0000

In Bytes

0000: 55 00 6E 00 69 00 73 00   U.n.i.s.
0008: 74 00 6F 00 72 00 65 00   t.o.r.e.
0010: 53 00 76 00 63 00 5F 00   S.v.c._.
0018: 53 00 65 00 73 00 73 00   S.e.s.s.
0020: 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 32 00   i.o.n.2.
0028: 00 00                     ..

[image]

Comment: This error is not specific but it is generated by the Service Control Manager when it detects that a specific service terminated ungracefully. **In order to troubleshoot this error look for other events, logs, etc., that are specific to the service in question**. [Event ID: 7031 Source: Service Control Manager](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-7031-source-Service%20Control%20Manager-eventno-465-phase-1.htm)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information from the "Details" tab.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have read the link that you provided, but there's no solution about user profile or related with my problem, thank you anyway for your command and support, +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was able to clear it up, same 4 errors every sign in with Event ID 7031. For me it was OneDrive, I had disabled it in the startup tab of task manager.

**If OneDrive is disabled in Startup tab of Task Manager, re-enable it. Disable through the application settings instead. To Disable: Right click on OneDrive in the tray, settings, settings tab, uncheck startup with windows.**

I'm not sure if just simply re-enabling on startup cleared the error or if I also needed to disable through the settings. I did both and not my errors are gone.

Answer (score -1):

Actually/maybe it's not the real answer, after few months i have found how to get rid those errors from event viewer, do not restart, log out or turn off your PC/laptop if the system do not ask for restart (such as the part of update process), just let the PC/laptop go to sleep and hibernate, as long we do not restart, log out or turn off the PC/laptop those error disappeared from event viewer.

Maybe Microsoft need user experience information from their product and do not want to loss the session connection (via internet) and give those errors at event viewer.